# Lista Ligada Java net beans

Tags: java

Tenho um problema que é basicamente um atendimento ao publico que consiste em criar um CRUD de clientes e depois selecionar um tipo de atendimento (A,B,C), e depois mostrar mostrar por ordem. Estou a usar LinkedList mas na parte de fazer o atendimento nao consigo guardar os dados. Qual seria a melhor maneira de fazer isto? Mudar a estrutura de dados? Devo criar um array com o nome de cliente e o atendimento e converter para lista?

Comment: Guardar você diz... manter na estrutura de dados até o programa fechar, certo?

Comment: nao, ao dizer o tipo de atendimento tenho que guardar na lista juntamente com o nome cliente